# Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the node [Bigquery Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery), to run a simple job.  Looking at the results (say `data`) of the job the `effective_date` attribute look like this:

```
 effective_date: BigQueryDate { value: '2015-10-02' }
```

which is obviously an object within the returned `data` object.

Importing the returned json into Firestore gives the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument "data" is not a 
valid Document. Couldn't serialize object of type "BigQueryDate". 
Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes 
(i.e. objects that were created via the 'new' operator).
```

Is there an elegant way to handle this? Does one need to iterate through the results and convert / remove all Objects?

Comment: Your probably need to add `.doc()` to the end of your firestore reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The firestore Node.js client do not support serialization of custom classes.

You will find more explanation in this issue:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/143
"We explicitly decided to not support serialization of custom classes for the Web and Node.JS client"

A solution is to convert the nested object to a plain object. For example by using lodash or JSON.stringify.

```
firestore.collection('collectionName')
    .doc('id')
    .set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myCustomObject)));
```

Here is a related post:
[Firestore: Add Custom Object to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578701/firestore-add-custom-object-to-db)

Comment: Using it this way stops you to set field values such as increments and array operations!

Comment: Also it breaks Date types.

Comment: Also breaks reference types. strongly disagree with this answer. If you need a workaround, go the Object.assign({}) way.

Answer (score 14):

Another way is less resource consuming:

```js
firestore
  .collection('collectionName')
  .doc('id')
  .set(Object.assign({}, myCustomObject));
```

Note: it works only for objects without nested objects.

Also you may use [`class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and it's `classToPlain()` along with [`exposeUnsetFields` option](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/35) to omit `undefined` values.

```bash
npm install class-transformer
or
yarn add class-transformer
```

```js
import {classToPlain} from 'class-transformer';

firestore
  .collection('collectionName')
  .doc('id')
  .set(instanceToPlain(myCustomObject, {exposeUnsetFields: false}));
```

Comment: this works better for me because if you have a date in your custom object, firestore will recornize it as timestamp. If you do the JSON.stringify() your date will become a string and this could be a nightmare later on

Comment: @AndreCytryn You can read more about date serialization issues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520674/returning-dates-server-timestamps-in-cloud-callable-functions and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format/15952652#15952652

Answer (score 7):

If you have a `FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp` object then don't use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` or `classToPlain(obj)` as those will corrupt it while storing to Firestore.

It's better to use `{...obj}` method.

```
firestore
  .collection('collectionName')
  .doc('id')
  .set({...obj});
```

Note: do not use `new` operator for any nested objects inside document class, it'll not work. Instead, create an `interface` or `type` for nested object properties like this:

```js
interface Profile {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

class User {
    id = "";
    isPaid = false;
    profile: Profile = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
    };
}

const user = new User();

user.profile.firstName = "gorv";

await firestore.collection("users").add({...user});
```

---

And if you really wanna store class object consists of deeply nested more class objects then use this function to first convert it to plain object while preserving `FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp` methods.

```js
const toPlainFirestoreObject = (o: any): any => {
  if (o && typeof o === "object" && !Array.isArray(o) && !isFirestoreTimestamp(o)) {
    return {
      ...Object.keys(o).reduce(
        (a: any, c: any) => ((a[c] = toPlainFirestoreObject(o[c])), a),
        {}
      ),
    };
  }
  return o;
};

function isFirestoreTimestamp(o: any): boolean {
  if (o && 
    Object.getPrototypeOf(o).toMillis &&
    Object.getPrototypeOf(o).constructor.name === "Timestamp"
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


const user = new User();

user.profile = new Profile();

user.profile.address = new Address();

await firestore.collection("users").add(toPlainFirestoreObject(user));
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this with converting a module to a class in Firestore. The issue was that I was using previously an admin firestore instance and referencing some field info from `@google-cloud` instead of using the methods in the firebase admin instance

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { FieldValue } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

await accountDocRef.set({
  createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

should use the references in the admin package instead:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

await accountDocRef.set({
  createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializes a value to a valid Firestore Document data, including `object` and its childs and `Array` and its items

```
export function serializeFS(value) {
    const isDate = (value) => {
        if(value instanceof Date || value instanceof firestore.Timestamp){
            return true;
        }
        try {
            if(value.toDate() instanceof Date){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (e){}

        return false;
    };

    if(value == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(
        typeof value == "boolean" ||
        typeof value == "bigint" ||
        typeof value == "string" ||
        typeof value == "symbol" ||
        typeof value == "number" ||
        isDate(value) ||
        value instanceof firestore.FieldValue
    ) {
        return value;
    }

    if(Array.isArray(value)){
        return (value as Array<any>).map((v) => serializeFS(v));
    }

    const res = {};
    for(const key of Object.keys(value)){
        res[key] = serializeFS(value[key]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Usage:

```
await db().collection('products').doc()
  .set(serializeFS(
     new ProductEntity('something', 123, FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  )));
```