# Returning dates / server timestamps in cloud callable functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a callable function from a client app to retrieve some data from firestore. The data is created using:

```
projectData = {
  created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  ...otherData
}
firebase.firestore().collection(projectsCollection).add(projectData)
```

And I can see the timestamp is correctly saved in the firestore console. The callable function does some other things and has error handling, but the data retrieval is done like this (using lodash to expand each document into an object to return to the client):

```
const projectRef = firestore.collection(gProjectsCollection).orderBy('created')
return projectRef.get().then(snapshot => {
  return {
    projects: _.chain(snapshot.docs)
      .keyBy('id')
      .mapValues(s => s.data())
      .value()
  }
})
```

This mostly works, but the returned object has a mangled `created` property (shown here in functions shell output):

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "result": {
     "projects": {
      "XcRyQyaxLguRdbNmxQdn": {
        "name": "c",
        "description": "c",
        "created": {
          "_seconds": 1543405587,
          "_nanoseconds": 169000000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm presuming this is because the callable function uses `JSON.stringify()` internally, and the server timestamp isn't converted correctly. I tried explicitly converting the timestamp to a date like this:

```
return projectRef.get().then(snapshot => {
  return {
    exVersion,
    exId,
    projects: _.chain(snapshot.docs)
      .keyBy('id')
      .mapValues(s => s.data())
      .forEach(d => { d.created = d.created.toDate() })
      .value()
  }
})
```

but now I get an empty object back:

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "result": {
    "projects": {
      "XcRyQyaxLguRdbNmxQdn": {
        "name": "c",
        "description": "c",
        "created": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect the real problem here is that callable functions aren't set up to return date objects. If I go one more step and convert the timestamp into a string, I finally get something back in the client:

```
return projectRef.get().then(snapshot => {
  return {
    exVersion,
    exId,
    projects: _.chain(snapshot.docs)
      .keyBy('id')
      .mapValues(s => s.data())
      .forEach(d => { d.created = d.created.toDate().toISOString() })
      .value()
  }
})
```

gives:

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "result": {
    "exVersion": 9,
    "exId": null,
    "projects": {
      "XcRyQyaxLguRdbNmxQdn": {
        "name": "c",
        "description": "c",
        "created": "2018-11-28T11:46:27.169Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation for callable functions about special handling for dates, but am I missing something in how this should be done?

---

Some further analysis in the callable function suggests `JSON.stringify()` is involved, but isn't the whole problem:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(d.created)):
info: {"_seconds":1543405587,"_nanoseconds":169000000}
JSON.stringify(d.created.toDate())
into: "2018-11-28T11:46:27.169Z"
```

So calling `d.created.toDate()` *should* be sufficient. But I've had other cases where `Date` objects are just not returned by callable functions, e.g.:

```
const testObject = {
  some: 'thing',
  d: new Date()
}

console.log('JSON:', JSON.stringify(testObject))

  return projectRef.get().then(snapshot => {
    return {
      testObject,
      projects: _.chain(snapshot.docs)
        .keyBy('id')
        .mapValues(s => s.data())
        .forEach(d => { console.log('d.created is:', JSON.stringify(d.created.toDate())); d.created = d.created.toDate() })
        .value()
    }
  })
```

Note in the output below, the logged results of `JSON.stringify()` on date objects seems to work, but when those objects are contained within the object returned from the function, they both come out as empty objects:

```
firebase > getAllProjects({uid: 1234})
Sent request to function.
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: JSON: {"some":"thing","d":"2018-11-28T13:22:36.841Z"}
info: Got 1 projects
info: d.created is: "2018-11-28T11:46:27.169Z"
info: Execution took 927 ms, user function completed successfully

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "result": {
    "testObject": {
      "some": "thing",
      "d": {}
    },
    "projects": {
      "XcRyQyaxLguRdbNmxQdn": {
        "description": "c",
        "created": {},
        "name": "c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting a serialized Date object to look like?  If you want it in some format, you should be explicit about that format, not just assume some serialization.

Comment: Something like `JSON.stringify(new Date())` or `new Date().toJSON()`. If I need a specific format, yes, but defaulting to nothing seems like the most surprising result.

Comment: This is what we call: **Missing in Action**. Unlike `ExpressJS`, it is automatically serialized to JSON.

Comment: @DougStevenson : If Firebase really need to default to something, at least default to `toISOString()` rather than `{}` -- since the Firebase team still need to default it to something if not explicitly formatted anyway. `{ }` is rather misleading, which may lead to whole day debugging.

Comment: @AntonioOoi If you have feedback or suggestions for Firebase, I suggest filing them with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result):

> To send data back to the client, return data that can be JSON encoded.

Since [`Date` is not a JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652), you will have to use your own serialization format for it (at least if you want it to be reliable/portable). From the linked answer it sounds like [`Date.toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) is a great candidate for that.

Comment: So returning the contents of `document.data()`, if that document contains a `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` just returns the 'internal' representation. And converting (as I have above) is the best way to get a consistent date string? It would seem to be such a common use case that the callable function wrapper logic could include some checks on that, or at least specifically mention it in the documentation. Same for `Date` objects within a document—seems like something very common to do.

Comment: Also, I'm curious how the callable functions actually do the conversion to JSON. I'm assuming it's _not_ via `JSON.stringify()`, otherwise the dates would come through as strings...

Comment: If you think the case could be handled better, I recommend [filing a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). To see how the conversion is actually done, have a look at the repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions

Comment: Looking at https.ts, it would be fairly easy to add `Date` support via `if _.isDate(data) { return data.toJSON() }` around line 365. I will file via the form, but also suggest the docs could be clarified. Since `Date.toJSON()` is a thing, saying "return data that can be JSON encoded" implies to me dates would be OK.

Comment: In fact, it would have to go at line 359, since `_.isObject(new Date())` returns `true`, but the subsequent call to `_.mapValues()` results in an empty object, so at least I know now where that empty object is coming from.