# How to insert NSDate value into a Cloud Firestore document

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I insert a time value from an NSDate into a Cloud Firestore document?

I can insert the current time like this but I'm not sure how to convert an `NSDate` to a `FIRFieldValue` representation.

```
NSMutableDictionary *item = [NSMutableDictionary new];
item[@"someDate"] = [FIRFieldValue fieldValueForServerTimestamp];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to add data to Firestore is in the form of a dictionary.

Firestore documentation (linked below) gives an example of this with an `NSDate` object, which I have trimmed and included below.

```
NSDictionary *docData = @{
  @"dateExample": [FIRTimestamp timestampWithDate:[NSDate date]]
};

[[[self.db collectionWithPath:@"data"] documentWithPath:@"one"] setData:docData
completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
  if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing document: %@", error);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Document successfully written!");
  }
}];
```

Otherwise, Firestore does not support storing custom objects. There are some roundabouts that make it pretty smooth, however... see [prev stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578701/firestore-add-custom-object-to-db) and [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#objective-c) (scroll to the custom objects section)